# filter json by timestamp year

Tags: jquery, json, filter, timestamp

I have a json array where i would like to get all objects where timestamp is from 2015.

JSON looks like this

```
    {
  "data": [
    { "name" : "blabla",
      "address": testtest,
      "timestampt": "2015-09-01T11:58:00.0000000Z"
      },
      { "name" : "blabla2",
      "address": testtest2,
      "timestampt": "2015-10-01T11:58:00.0000000Z"
      },
      { "name" : "blabla3",
      "address": testtest3,
      "timestampt": "2014-10-01T11:58:00.0000000Z"
]}
```

Is there some simple way to search for ex 2015 using jQuery or js?

hope you can help me with this

Comment: Just some small errors in your code:
1) `testtest` should be in quotes if it's not a reference to an object
2) There's a `}` missing at the end of the last item (before the closing `]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must get your JSON right - quotes around values. Then, you could use `Array.filter()` to that :

```
var json2015 = json.data.filter(function(item) {
    if (new Date(item.timestampt).getFullYear() == 2015) return item;
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/taddow3y/**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter`, so something like this:

```
json.data.filter(function(obj) {
  return new Date(obj.timestampt).getYear() === 115;
});
```

It's `115` because it's the years from 1900.
Best.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you for your quick answers.
I choose to use this solution

```
var json2015 = json.data.filter(function(item) {
    if (new Date(item.timestampt).getFullYear() == 2015) return item;
})
```

and just change 2015 with selected option value :)